# Time-consuming problem of inserting 10,000,000 elements into ArrayList and LinkedList

Tags: java, list

I have some problems when I test the time it takes to insert `10,000,000` elements into `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`. When I put the test code at both ends in two `main()` functions, the time spent on the `LinkedList` **is greater than about** `ArrayList`, which is about twice.

When I put both ends of the code in the same `main()` method and the `ArrayList` is inserted first, the `ArrayList` takes longer than the `LinkedList`, which is about twice as large. I want to know what happened?
In theory, it should be that `ArrayList` takes less time.

**The first piece of code:**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long begin2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<Integer> l2 = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        l2.add(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    long end2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(end2 - begin2); //Time: 12362

}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long begin1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        l1.add(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    long end1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(end1 - begin1); //Time: 7531
}
```

**Second piece of code:**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long begin1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        l1.add(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    long end1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(end1 - begin1); //Time: 7555

    long begin2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<Integer> l2 = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        l2.add(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    long end2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(end2 - begin2); //Time: 3533

 }
```

**The next code makes me even more confused, because the time difference between the two pieces of code is not so obvious：**

```java
`public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long begin1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            l1.add(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        }
        long end1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(end1 - begin1); //Time: 4542

        long begin2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<Integer> l2 = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            l2.add(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        }
        long end2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(end2 - begin2); //Time: 4325
    }`
```

Comment: Your second piece of code didn't remove the first list from memory, and the JVM was already "warmed up"

Comment: @aku why is the time difference being small confuse you? Both ArrayList and LinkedList have an amortized insertion time of O(1). The main difference is that ArrayList may have to double its size + copy once it gets past a certain point, and LinkedList just allocates a new node + inserts to the back.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into this a bit more the cause seems to be with JVM

take a look at this code / results

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

        long begin0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<Integer> l0 = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            l0.add(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        }
        long end0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(end0 - begin0); //Time: 12992

        long begin1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            l1.add(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        }
        long end1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(end1 - begin1); //Time: 1277

        long begin2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<Integer> l2 = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            l2.add(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        }
        long end2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(end2 - begin2); //Time: 1455
    }
```

Notice that the first loop that runs takes a significantly longer time than the third loop even though it's the exact same code.

Seems like the cause is startup time overhead

[Why is the JVM slow to start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844143/why-is-the-jvm-slow-to-start)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_performance#Startup_time

Comment: For CPU problems, After I run the code multiple times, the results are almost the same.

Comment: For caching problems,ArrayList and LinkedList use different data structures. LinkedList is composed of multiple nodes. Each node is an object of internal class Node, so I think it should not be a cache problem.

Comment: For the precision of System.currentTimeMillis(),I use the long type to record the timestamp, and I think the current return value has not reached the magnitude of the precision problem.

Comment: For the compiler optimization,I am not familiar with the bytecode instructions. I decompile the .class files and found no big differences. Can you please help analyze it?

Comment: So I just ran this myself, it seems like it's most likely something with JVM. I'll edit my original comment with the final results.

Comment: The JVM should be started successfully before the main() method is executed, so I don't think it is a startup time issue. But the comparison of the next two pieces of code made me confused.I'll edit my question to show this.

Comment: Clearly whatever is causing this side effect has to do with some operation going on at the start of the application. Perhaps it's the garbage collector starting up, or some other startup operation running on a different thread.